# How to update .Net 4.x application without updating any dlls/exe?

Tags: .net, dll, desktop-application, auto-update

I need to develop the auto update mechanism for the desktop application built using .Net 4.0 or 4.5. It should not download or update any dlls or exe files. This is the corporate policy, I can't change it.

However it is allowed to download any kind of scripts, c# code, xml, json, xaml etc that can be stored in the  SQL database that this application is using.

Any ideas how to build this kind of updater? Any standard approach or framework for this?

Comment: Download a `.doc` and rename it to `.exe`.

Comment: What do you do once you have a code-related bug that you need to update?  This seems like "not a real question" to me...

Comment: Here you go: never have the DLLs on the workstation at all. Retrieve a base-64 text encoded version of any DLL from your database and decode and load it dynamically on the client. Therefore, the app is always updated. But this requires planning beforehand, as not being able to update dlls or exes on the workstation is kinda, well, pointless.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. In my case I can not _download_ exe or dll as well, it may be considered as a policy break. However I can download any scripts, xml and build the application on the client side.

Comment: @user695797: DO you have source control? If so, install a 'build server' (eg Jenkins or similar) to build it for you. Or use msbuild (and msbuildextensions) on the client side to pull source from source control and build project.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the reqirement of not "Downloading binaries" you will need to use the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) to turn your .cs files in to assemblies, which can then be loaded as I describe in my original answer. [Here is a good tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime) on Code Project on how to use the class to compile your .cs code at run-time.

---

**Original answer:**

To expand on [Jesse's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976540/how-to-update-net-4-x-application-without-updating-any-dlls-exe#comment17598189_12976540). Your main program will need to be a simple loader that can query the "Program database" that contains the real files.

There are 2 phases to the loading process: Bootstrap AppDomin, Load assemblies

---

To bootstrap your app domain you will need create a new AppDomain, restrict it to loading only signed files, then load a loader that loads the rest of the DLL's

Inside your code you will need to [create a new AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130766%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to load the files in to. In that app domain you will want to create a [evidence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.policy.evidence%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that only allows assemblies that are [signed by your private key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.policy.publisher.publisher%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to be loaded.

```
//Assumes you have your X509Certificate (the version that only has the public key)
// stored in Settings.Resources.
var onlySignedByMe = new Publisher(Settings.Resources.MyCompanyCertificate);

var evidence = new Evidence();
evedence.(onlySignedByMe);

var adi = new AppDomainInitializer(AppDomainInit);

var appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
appDomainSetup.AppDomainInitializer = adi;
appDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;

var programAppDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("programAppDomain", evidence, appDomainSetup, PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));
```

When the AppDomian initializes it will call AppDomainInit from the new domain. From there query the database for any assemblies it needs to load. Load those files in to a `byte[]` then load the `byte[]` using the [Load method on the AppDomain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7hcs6az6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
private static void AppDomainInit(string[] args)
{
    List<Byte[]> assemblies;

    //Snip, populating the list;

    Asesembly entryAssembly;
    foreach(var assembly in assemblies)
    {
         var loadedAssembly = Assembly.Load(assembly);
         if(TestForKnownEntryPointAssembly(loadedAssembly)
             entryAssembly = loadedAssembly;
    }
    if(entryAssembly != null)
    {
        Type type = entryAssembly.GetType("MyNamespace.EntryClass");
        MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("Main");
        method.Invoke(null, null);
    }

}
```

---

This was all written from memory so there may be some errors.

Comment: so I have do download the dlls? Unfortunately I can not do it due to corporate policy. But I can download any kind of scripts, c# code, xml, json, xaml etc. Any ideas?

Comment: If you can not download a binary, how do you expect to replace a binary. And why would downloading the source then compiling the code on a client computer (that could modify the code before it was complied) be considered more secure than a digitally signed file that is guaranteed not to be modified?

Comment: Scott, these are the rules of a huge corp, some of them are outdated, others are stupid, but I need to solve task without trying to modify them. I am 100% sure it is possible to download c# source, compile it and attach XAML if required on the fly, no need to update any dlls and this will work for me. However there may be more simple or better approaches. Your answer is incorrect, because I clearly specified that my application can not download any dll or exe (all updates must do through SMS, which is not an option for me). It also makes no sense to "rename" .dll to .doc, this breaks policy.

Comment: I have updated my answer with some links that will help you turn your .cs file in to an assembly, you then load the assembly using the steps I showed. The tutorial I linked also shows the assembly loading steps.

Comment: "all updates must do through SMS" too many things have the acronym SMS, which one are you referring to?